Movie about a writer
I watched a movie few years back on TV, in which there was a writer who was writing book about a girl and coincidentally during that time a girl comes in his life who resembles the girl in his book. He realizes it later and whenever he makes any changes related to that girl in his book, the girl in his life  starts to behave like that. I am unable to recall what movie it was, I don't even remember if it was French or English. Can anybody help?

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

I believe you're looking for the film Ruby Sparks.

Ruby Sparks is a 2012 romantic comedy-drama film directed by Jonathan Dayton and Valerie Faris, and written by Zoe Kazan. It stars Paul Dano as an anxious novelist whose fictional character, Ruby Sparks, played by Kazan, comes to life.

Here's the trailer:



